# SSRS Interactive sorting, Parent Child or Group Datasets

Tags: reporting-services, dataset

New to SSRS and setup a report for Sales Group by Region.  We have sales teams that are supervised by the National team and more than 1 employee can be in the same sales region.  I have an SSRS report built on a query that retrieves all Groups and sales regions.

I would like the user to be able to select from a drop down to filter by Team and Sales Region or select from a picklist.  Not sure if I should add and interactive sort or group datasets, or what i need to do here.

1. Team: Northeast, East
2. Sales Region: East, Northeast

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you just need to add two PARAMETERS to your report - one for Team and the other for Sales. This will allow a user to filter the data by either.

Add a Parameter by opening the Report Data, right click on Parameter and Add Parameter.

Name your first parameter TEAM. Check the Allow Multiple Values to let users select more than one at a time.

In the Available Values tab, click on Specify Values and add your two teams on separate lines.

In the Default Values tab, click on Specify Values and select your two teams on separate lines.

Repeat the parameter creation for REGION.

To add the parameter filter to the dataset, open your dataset and go to the Filters tab. Click Add. Select your TEAM field for the Expression. Change the Operator to IN. For the Value, select your Parameter. Repeat the Filter creation for REGION.

Now your report will show all values when it's first run but can be filtered by TEAM and/or REGION.